# MySQL group and select only first from each group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I would like to perform a query that will select only the most recent item from a given group.

---

In this example, I'm tracking vans:

- Each time they return to base, a `check-in` is recorded with information - mileage, etc...
- Each time they make a delivery, a `delivery` is recorded - customer, etc...

This table lets us know the history for a given `van`. The data can be produced with a query or stored as we go - this isn't the problem.

```
 id | checkin_id | delivery_id | van_id
----+------------+-------------+--------
 24 | 15         | NULL        | 3
 25 | NULL       | 28          | 3
 26 | 16         | NULL        | 4
 27 | NULL       | 29          | 3
 28 | NULL       | 30          | 4
 29 | 17         | NULL        | 5
```

---

I can see the van's history by querying with  `... WHERE van_id=3;` - fine.

Conversely, I would like to be able to get a list of `vans` with their most recent "*event*". Resulting in this:

```
 id | checkin_id | delivery_id | van_id
----+------------+-------------+--------
 27 | NULL       | 29          | 3
 28 | NULL       | 30          | 4
 29 | 17         | NULL        | 5
```

---

I jumped to the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `history` GROUP BY `van_id`;
```

But this returns the following error:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.history.checkin_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

After reading up, I understand what this is about and have to admit that my SQL is somewhat out of date - *which of the items from the group do I want returned?*

Adding `checkin_id` and `delivery_id` to the `GROUP BY` just shifts the problem - Ultimately I end up with the same set of data, just sorted differently.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38551525) piqued my interest, and the graphic really helps to clearly outline the problem, thanks @azerafati!

I want to use the `FIRST()` or `LAST()` aggregate function - [but MySQL doesn't appear to have them](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

How do I reproduce this behaviour without processing *all* of the data in my application?

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Then you won't have this error.

Comment: The reason you get that particular error is because recent versions of MySQL default to disallowing it. As far as I know, MySQL is the only RDBMS that allows it at all; the problem is that unless the non-grouped, non-aggregated fields selected are "functionally dependent" on the grouped ones, the values used are not guaranteed to be a specific one encountered (effectively a random selection from those encountered in the process of grouping). Basically, if your configuration allowed it, your query could get a result row like (27, 15, 28, 3).

Comment: You can tell how your code doesn't make sense.  When you grouping by `van_id`, and you don't put aggregation on `checkin_id` and `delivery_id`, how would MySQL know which one to get??  For `van_id 3`, why `checkin_id` is `NULL`, not 15???  Why would `delivery_id` is `29`, not `NULL`???

Comment: You are trying to use MySQL's deprecated non-standard extension to `GROUP BY`. Please read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess your `id` values are unique, and later records have higher values than earlier records.

You need to use a subquery that gets the latest `id` for each van:

```
         SELECT MAX(id) id, van_id
           FROM history
          GROUP BY van_id
```

Then join that to your detail query.

```
 SELECT h.*
   FROM history h
   JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(id) id, van_id
           FROM history
          GROUP BY van_id
        ) m ON h.id = m.id AND h.van_id = m.van_id
```

But because your id values are unique you can simplify this even more.

```
 SELECT h.*
   FROM history h
   JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(id) id
           FROM history
          GROUP BY van_id
        ) m ON h.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 4):

I was going to mark this as a duplicate because the question is actually asked fairly frequently, but I found those question/answers seem fairly hard to search for; so here is the generic template:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM theTable AS t
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT groupingValue, MIN(someValue) AS lowestValue
   FROM theTable
   GROUP BY groupingValue
) AS rIdent ON rIdent.groupingValue = t.groupingValue AND rIdent.lowestValue= t.someValue
```

*lowest* in your particular case being the min(id)...oh, oops; your question says first, but the detail says most recent (which I would interpret as last), so just use MAX instead of MIN. *...and the "groupingValue" is van_id.*

Edit: The query should be fairly efficient if there is an index on the grouping fields and the field used to identify lowest/first/highest/recent .

Comment: Thanks - I'll play... I've addressed the first/most recent ambiguity.

Comment: The similar questions should all be tagged [tag:greatest-n-per-group].